# How to reach certain item in FlatList when onEndReached called?(react-native)

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am displaying 20 items for the first time when **FlatList** is loaded. Once user reaches to end of the list again fetching 20 more items and adding those items to previous list and then displaying those 40 items. But the problem is, when the items are loaded second time I will have to scroll again from first item, but not the 21'st item. Here is my **FlatList**,

```
<FlatList
    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
    data={this.props.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderCardItems(item, index)} 
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    onEndReached={this.loadMore}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0}
/>
```

loadMore() does the fetching operation

```
axios.get('url').then((res) => {
        res.data.main.map(function(a) {
          var itemFound = false;
          for(var i=0;i<this.props.data.length;i++) {
                if(a.id == this.props.data[i].id) {
                    itemFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!itemFound)
                this.props.data.push(a);
        }.bind(this));
        //Calling Action creator to keep data in Application state.
        this.props.updateListState('App Data', this.props.data);
```

Could you let me know how can I go to the some particular item when **onEndReached** called?

Comment: this shouldn't happen, can you provide more code related to the FlatList?

Comment: Could you please provide the code for ```this.loadMore```?

Comment: @htkibar I have updated question with this.loadMore().

Comment: @Shubhnik Sing, I have added some more code